# How to scroll to element (Appium+Selenium) for iOS devices?

Tags: ios, appium

I have a command for Android, but i don't know how to realise it for iOS.

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable("new  
 UiSelector())".scrollIntoView(text(\"Radio Group\"));");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript executer.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

change direction to up if you want to swipe up